# AG Grid Charts Labels Not displaying

Tags: charts

I'm evaluating AG Grid Charts in angular 8. I've created integrated chart (range chart), chart is creating but axes labels and legend labels are not displaying. Can somebody help me. The same is working properly in Angular 10.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/de8oP.jpg)

Need help from experts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.